# np.vectorize giving out nan values in ETS time series forecasting

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, nan, ets

re_1=np.vectorize(ETStest)(Trend_seasonal['trend'],Trend_seasonal['seasonal'],seasonal_period=12,i = 0)

This is the line which is showing me the error

```
    def ets_pred (train):
       trend=['add', 'add', 'mul','mul']
       sea=  ['add', 'mul', 'mul','add']
       Trend_seasonal=pd.DataFrame()
       Trend_seasonal['trend']=trend
       Trend_seasonal['seasonal']=sea
       re_1=np.vectorize(ETStest) (Trend_seasonal['trend'],Trend_seasonal['seasonal'],seasonal_period=12,i = 0)
       result_table_ETS=pd.DataFrame(re_1).transpose()
       result_table_ETS.columns=['Trend','Seasonal','seasonal_period','error_mae_f','error_mae_p','Accuracy_mae_f','Accuracy_mae_p','Diff','Product','mae_pm','mae_smly','MAE_CV']  result_table_ETS_1=result_table_ETS[~result_table_ETS.Trend.str.contains("Fals")].dropna()
       result_table_ETS_1 = result_table_ETS_1.sort_values(by='MAE_CV', ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
       return(result_table_ETS_1)
```

Following is the place where I am calling the function

```
    run_results = pd.DataFrame()
    forecast_results = pd.DataFrame()
    model_result=[]

    for i in df.columns:
      ts = df[i]
      n=uservalue
      train, test = ts[0:len(ts)-n], ts[len(ts)-n:]
      train1, test1 = ts[0:len(ts)], ts[0:len(ts)]

      re = ets_pred(train)
      re['Target'] = pd.DataFrame({'Target' : np.tile([i], len(re))})['Target']
      re['Refresh_month'] = pd.DataFrame({'Target' : np.tile([ref_month], len(re))})['Target']
      run_results=run_results.append(re)
      run_results=run_results.fillna(0)
  
      display(re)
      optimal_row = 0
      model_ETS= ExponentialSmoothing( endog=ts, trend=re.iloc[optimal_row,0], seasonal=re.iloc[optimal_row,1], 
                                    
      seasonal_periods=re.iloc[optimal_row,2],damped=True, dates=None, freq=None, missing='none').fit()
      res = model_ETS.fittedvalues[-10:]
      print(res)
      predictions_ETS = model_ETS.predict(start=len(train),end=len(train)+n-1)
      predictions = predictions_ETS
            
      error_ETS_mae_f = re.iloc[optimal_row,3]
      error_ETS_mae_p = re.iloc[optimal_row,4]
      print('Summary of Best Model')
      display(model_ETS.summary())
      model_result.append([i,
        ref_month,
        re.iloc[optimal_row,0],
        re.iloc[optimal_row,1],
        re.iloc[optimal_row,2],
        model_ETS.params['smoothing_level'],
        #model_ETS.params['smoothing_trend'],
        model_ETS.params['smoothing_seasonal'],
        #model_ETS.params['damping_trend'],
        model_ETS.params['initial_level'],
        #model_ETS.params['initial_trend'],
        re.iloc[optimal_row,5],
        re.iloc[optimal_row,6],
        re.iloc[optimal_row,7],
        re.iloc[optimal_row,8]])
    
   
forecast=pd.DataFrame()
forecast['Date'] = model_ETS.predict(start=len(train), end=len(train)+20).index
forecast['Forecast'] = model_ETS.predict(start=len(train), end=len(train)+20).values
forecast['Target'] = pd.DataFrame({'Target' : np.tile([i], len(forecast))})['Target']
forecast['Refresh_month'] = pd.DataFrame({'Target' : np.tile([ref_month], len(forecast))})['Target']
forecast_results=forecast_results.append(forecast)
display(forecast)
```

I think that np.vectorize is giving out some nan values and that is why I am getting the error. The above is the function for the same

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why are you using `np.vectorize`?  It doesn't look like you are needing its `broadcasting` ability.  It is slower than a more direct iteration, and often harder to use right.

Comment: What's this `ETStest` function?

Comment: def ETStest(trend, sea, seasonal_period,i):
    
    try:
            model= ExponentialSmoothing( endog=train, trend=trend, damped=True, seasonal=sea, 
                                seasonal_periods=seasonal_period, dates=None, freq=None, missing='none').fit()       return(trend, 
                   sea, 
                   seasonal_period     except: print("NaN")